# Intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation

Given that:
[image]

Where $\mathcal{A_i}$ for every $i \in \mathrel{I}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, I do not quite follow the proof:

[image]

Because it states that the sequence is an element of every $\mathcal{A_i}$. But what if you take some sets from $\mathcal{A_1}$, then some from $\mathcal{A_2}$. For example, let's take some odd indexed sets from $\mathcal{A_1}$, i.e. $\cup_i A_i$, where $i \in \mathrel{I} := \{ \text{all odd natural numbers} \}$, some even from $\mathcal{A_2}$, i.e. $\cup_j A_j$, then why is $\cup_i A_i \cup \cup_j A_j \in \mathcal{A}_I$.

I think I just realized. Because we take intersections, that is why those sequences are in all of the individual $\sigma$-algebras. Is this correct?

Comment: What you realized is correct. Intersections is the key here.

Comment: thanks. hmm, not sure what to do with this question then. Shall I delete it?

Comment: I can't comment on whether you should delete it or not. It's purely your personal choice. :)